# SQL Server insert into with dynamic parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to make a dynamic stored procedure for inserting records in tables where I pass in table name, schema name and insert values parameters.

I've made it to select column names from table parameter and store it in a variable, but I can't manage how to make insert statement work.

Please if anyone can help me.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @VALUES NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SchemaName = 'dbo'
SET @TableName = 'CLASSROOMS'
SET @Columns = '';
SET @VALUES = 'Classroom1,25'

SELECT @Columns = @Columns + CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS varchar(50)) + ','
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName 
  AND ORDINAL_POSITION > 1

SET @Columns = SUBSTRING(@Columns, 1, Len(@Columns) - 1)

--SELECT @Columns

DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL=N'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + '(' + @Columns + ') VALUES (' + @VALUES + ')'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

And here is `Classroom` table create script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CLASSROOMS]
(
    [ClassRoomID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClassRoomName] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [MaxSits] [INT] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CLASSROOMS] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ClassRoomID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @VALUES='''Classroom1'',25'
```

The `[ClassRoomName]` is a nvarchar field.

Comment: Yes, That's it, Thank you very much.. When a men is frustrated can't see that :) Thank's Again

Comment: @bruno beat me by seconds! I normally comment out the `EXEC` statement and do a `Select @SQL` instead. I can then copy and paste this to a new query and run it to check if it works! Makes debugging a lot easier!

Comment: @bruno.almeida What about some example for dynamic update?

Comment: Well, first of all i strongly advice you to not do inserts or updates that way. It is very error prone and can create security flaws. If i can, i always use Entity Framework (but exists many others).That said, what is your concern about dynamic update? But is better open a new question with it, instead of talking about other off-topic issues.